# How to use Winston in Rollup-bundled Sapper app for logging?

Tags: winston, rollupjs, sapper

I am trying to get the Winston logging library working with my Sapper app. That Sapper app uses Rollup as module bundler. To implement my app, I basically followed the following steps:

Start new Sapper project that uses Rollup:

```
npx degit "sveltejs/sapper-template#rollup" my-app
```

Install winston via `npm install winston` and add custom logger factory in file `src/_logging.js`:

```js
import { createLogger, transports, format } from 'winston';

export function createLabeledLogger(label) {
  return createLogger({
    level: 'debug',
    transports: [new transports.Console()],
    format: format.combine(
      format.label({ label: label, message: true }),
      format.splat(),
      format.padLevels(),
      format.simple(),
    )
  });

}
```

Obtain the logger via the factory and use the logger in *server* route `src/routes/blog/_posts.js`:

```js
import { createLabeledLogger } from '../../_logging';
const logger = createLabeledLogger('posts-server');

const posts = [
// ...
];

posts.forEach(post => {
// ...
});

logger.debug(`Created ${posts.length} posts for client.`)
```

This works like a charm:

```
✔ service worker (16ms)
debug:    [posts-server] Created 5 posts for client.
> Listening on http://localhost:5001
```

However, I've been struggling with getting that logger working in the browser.

For that purpose, I introduced the logger in *client* route `src/routes/blog/index.svelte`:

```js
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { createLabeledLogger } from '../../_logging';
    const logger = createLabeledLogger('posts-page');

    export let posts;

    onMount(() => {
        // console.log(`Obtained ${posts.length} posts from server.`)
        logger.debug(`Obtained ${posts.length} posts from server.`)
    });

</script>
```

This caused the following error:

```
✗ client
Unexpected token (Note that you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files)
1: {
2:   "_from": "winston",
            ^
3:   "_id": "winston@3.2.1",
4:   "_inBundle": false,
```

So, I installed that suggested plugin via

```
npm install --save-dev @rollup/plugin-json
```

and modified `rollup.config.js` to import the plugin (`import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';`) and to use it in the client bundle (`json()`).

While this fixes above "JSON" issue, it causes new trouble:

```
'util' is imported by node_modules/winston/dist/winston/common.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'os' is imported by node_modules/winston/dist/winston/exception-handler.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'os' is imported by node_modules/winston/dist/winston/rejection-handler.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'util' is imported by util?commonjs-external, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'os' is imported by os?commonjs-external, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'os' is imported by node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/file.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'os' is imported by node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/console.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'os' is imported by node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/stream.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'util' is imported by node_modules/winston-transport/dist/index.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'path' is imported by node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/file.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'zlib' is imported by node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/file.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'fs' is imported by node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/file.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'https' is imported by node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/http.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'http' is imported by node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/http.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
[...]
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41506330), I installed `rollup-plugin-node-builtins`, and added it to `rollup.config.js` analogously to the JSON plugin (`import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins';` and `builtins()`).

This again solves above "could not be resolved" issues -- and again causes new trouble:

```
preferring built-in module 'string_decoder' over local alternative at '/private/tmp/mburger/my-app/node_modules/string_decoder/lib/string_decoder.js', pass 'preferBuiltins: false' to disable this behavior or 'preferBuiltins: true' to disable this warning
preferring built-in module 'string_decoder' over local alternative at '/private/tmp/mburger/my-app/node_modules/string_decoder/lib/string_decoder.js', pass 'preferBuiltins: false' to disable this behavior or 'preferBuiltins: true' to disable this warning
preferring built-in module 'string_decoder' over local alternative at '/private/tmp/mburger/my-app/node_modules/string_decoder/lib/string_decoder.js', pass 'preferBuiltins: false' to disable this behavior or 'preferBuiltins: true' to disable this warning
preferring built-in module 'string_decoder' over local alternative at '/private/tmp/mburger/my-app/node_modules/string_decoder/lib/string_decoder.js', pass 'preferBuiltins: false' to disable this behavior or 'preferBuiltins: true' to disable this warning
preferring built-in module 'string_decoder' over local alternative at '/private/tmp/mburger/my-app/node_modules/string_decoder/lib/string_decoder.js', pass 'preferBuiltins: false' to disable this behavior or 'preferBuiltins: true' to disable this warning
```

Okay, so I set `preferBuiltins` to `false`. New trouble arises:

```
Circular dependency: node_modules/winston-transport/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> node_modules/winston-transport/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js -> node_modules/winston-transport/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/winston-transport/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> node_modules/winston-transport/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js -> /private/tmp/mburger/my-app/node_modules/winston-transport/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js?commonjs-proxy -> node_modules/winston-transport/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/winston-transport/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js -> node_modules/winston-transport/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> node_modules/winston-transport/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/winston-transport/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js -> node_modules/winston-transport/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> /private/tmp/mburger/my-app/node_modules/winston-transport/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js?commonjs-proxy -> node_modules/winston-transport/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/readable-stream/duplex.js -> node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/readable-stream/readable.js -> node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/readable-stream/duplex.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/readable-stream/duplex.js -> node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/readable-stream/writable.js -> node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/readable-stream/duplex.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js -> /private/tmp/mburger/my-app/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js?commonjs-proxy -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> /private/tmp/mburger/my-app/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js?commonjs-proxy -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js
```

Now, I followed the instructions at [this comment](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1507#issuecomment-340550539) and adapted my `rollup.config.js` file accordingly.

Again, a new issue occurs:

```
Could not resolve './stream/duplex.js' from node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/stream.js
```

Well, following the instruction at [this README](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/rollup-plugin-node-builtins#readme), I installed `rollup-plugin-node-globals` and added it to my `rollup.config.js` file (`import globals from 'rollup-plugin-node-globals';`, `globals()`).

This results in a similar issue:

```
Could not resolve './stream/writable.js' from node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/stream.js
```

I have researched in various Stack Overflow entries, GitHub issue trackers and Google.

Is it possible to use Winston in a Sapper app that uses Rollup as bundler?

Incidentally, to successfully use Winston with the webpack version of the Sapper app, all it required to get it running was to add `node: { fs: 'empty' },` to `webpack.config.js` -- as this output in the Web Developer console shows:

```
debug:    [posts-page] Obtained 5 posts from server.
```

**Update on June 2**

You can find the [complete rollup.config.js file](https://gist.github.com/martinburger/7c56185080055315c78e94ff1d6c8b94) as GitHub Gist.

Please note that it neither worked with `preferBuiltins` set to `true` nor with set to `false`.

**Update on June 3**

The slow descent into the inner circles of (dev) hell continues:

Following ThomasHennes' suggestion, I added the following symlink:

```
❯ la node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/stream
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mburger  wheel    15B Jun  3 12:45 node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/stream -> readable-stream
```

And again, a different issue comes to light:

```
• client
'stream/writable' is imported by stream/writable?commonjs-external, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'stream/writable' is imported by node_modules/winston-transport/dist/index.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
Circular dependency: node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/readable-stream/duplex.js -> node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/readable-stream/readable.js -> node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/readable-stream/duplex.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/readable-stream/duplex.js -> node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/readable-stream/writable.js -> node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6/readable-stream/duplex.js
```

Comment: A very well documented question that reads like Dante's slow descent into the inner circles of (dev) hell. Joking aside, could you post your rollup.config.js file as it stands after all modifications, please? Have you attempted setting `preferBuiltins: true` in that earlier step - and did it change anything?

Comment: @ThomasHennes: It definitely felt that way. It took me almost a whole day to test different settings and to distill above findings. Please note that I added a link to my rollup.config.js file. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Thank you for the update Martin! What I find really, really odd is that the build now errors on resolving `./stream/writable.js` after you managed to fix resolving `./stream/duplex.js` when *both originate in the same library*. Looking inside https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/blob/master/src/es6/stream.js, `writable.js` is imported from a *local* `./readable-stream` directory. Could it be that your aliasing `readable-stream` into `stream` interferes and causes the resolver to fail?

Comment: What you *could* try - and this is nothing more than a hack for experimental purposes, not a bona fide solution - is to create a `stream` symlink that points to the `readable-stream` directory inside `node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/src/es6`, and see if it fixes your error.